# BULK IMPORT the same data multiple times require very different time. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I'm testing the speed of BCP utility. I'm using the same database, table, data file (10 million lines), format file etc. in different experiments. After each experiment, I drop table and create the new one (exactly the same). When BCP utility doesn't work my HDD performance loaded on 1-5% (I use Task Manager to check it). When it works HDD loaded on 99%.

BUT.

I had 6 experiments now. The best is 178 sec the worst is 292 sec!!!

I will need to compare BCP to other methods, figure out what influences on speed (for example indexes, constraints, recovery settings etc) and how big is this influence. But I can't do it now because of such big differences between same experiments.

Why it happens and can I fix it?

UPD: I changed recovery model to "full" from "simple" and made more experiments. Now the best time is 173 sec the worst is 435 sec :)

Comment: For all these tests i think your are making sure source IO, destination IO and processing capabilities are similar... Because primarily in destination IO a small change in INDEX in destination table will provide different results

Comment: What you are trying to find BCP vs BULK insert?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I'm not trying to find I need to have my own results. I'm writing graduate work

Comment: What is this question for?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I can't compare different methods when the same method gives random results

Comment: During both the execution is there change in the target table structure?

Comment: You should check your database statistics to see where the difference is. In Oracle an AWR report would help, in this environment I do not know what the proper tool is, but there must be some.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy of course not as I said in question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to test Nonlogged BULK INSERT

1. Recovery mode set to `SELECT INTO/BULK INSERT`
2. Add `TABLOCK`

```sql
BULK INSERT TestDB
FROM 'C:\TestDB.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    TABLOCK
)
```